# Должно ли чтение поля int быть синхронизировано?

Tags: java, многопоточность

В книге Java Concurrency на практике приложен примерно такой код:

```
public class Counter {
    private long value = 0;

    public synchronized long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public synchronized void increment() {
        ++value;
    }
}
```

Здесь поле value с типом long, а также синхронизированные методы чтения и инкремента.

Я правильно понимаю, что синхронизация метода чтения нужна лишь для типов long и double, ведь они не являются атомарными? И если поле value будет с типом int, синхронизация метода чтения будет ненужной?

Comment: Будет нужна всё равно. Иначе процессор закэширует значение и перестанет из памяти его читать перед каждым инкрементом, т.к. каждый поток будет модифицировать свою копию, не синхронизируясь с другими потоками.

Answer (score 1):

Синхронизация метода чтения нужна для `int` тоже.

Помимо атомарности `synchronized` также гарантирует, что чтение переменной всегда возвращает последнее записанное в неё значение.
Обычно именно это и подразумевают под "синхронизацией".

Если у метода чтения убрать `synchronized`, то возникает так называемая гонка (data race).
В этом случае чтение каждый раз может рандомно возвращать любое из значений, когда-либо записанных в эту переменную с момента запуска программы.